# Am I correctly calculating the density altitude?

Tags: temperature, theory, density-altitude

I came across the following question while studying for the FAA PPL written test:

> Determine the density altitude for these conditions:
>
> Altimeter setting: 30.35
> Runway temperature: +25°F
> Airport elevation: 3,894 ft. MSL

I performed the following steps:

Temperature (°C) $\color{red}{= 5/9 × 25} = 14 $

Pressure altitude (PA) $= 3,894 + (29.92-30.35) × 930 = 3494 $

Density altitude (DA) $= \text{PA} + 120(14 - 15 + .002×\text{PA}) = 4200 $

Yet that answer is not listed, and according to the DA/PA graph provided, DA is 2000ft.

My final formula seems to be correct [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_altitude#Calculation), plus it also matches my intuition of how PA works: According to the question we have 14°C at 4000ft, as opposed to the expected 7°C at 4000ft; seeing as temperature is higher, DA should be higher than PA.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using 930 instead of 1,000 in you calculation of Pressure altitude? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_altitude. Also, where did the second PA term in the DA formula come from? Not something I use. You might want to check out http://www.flyingmag.com/technique/tip-week/calculating-density-altitude-pencil

Comment: @JScarry:  930ft/inHg is the correct factor at about 29.92 — 28.92 inHg; for higher altitudes it increases; thank you for bringing that to my attention, I'll probably use 1000 from now on.  The $.002×\text{PA}$ is to correct for lapse rate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your temperature conversion: 25F is -3.9C...

Should be (25-32)*(5/9).

Comment: Yep, I suspected I'd goofed up with something as stupid as a conversion error.  I'd answered several questions about *change* of density altitude with *change* of temperature, where you *can* forget the $-32$, and am embarrassed to say I went and did the same thing here.

Comment: I'm studying for the commercial and CFI exams - there are plenty of ways to mess up!  Happy to help.